# XSLT element selection based on another variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

New to XSLT and i am trying with below xsl file in which i would like to select a particular code based on another variable with in the same XSL. using Saxon-He-10.5 version jar. Could some one help me with this xsl transformation. i would like to print the title of selected code in output.xml

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xpath-default-namespace="http://test.org/test"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
  xmlns:lookup="http://lookup.data"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fn lookup xsl xsi">

<xsl:variable name="key1" select="&quot;status1&quot;"/>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:variable name="header">
    <sections>
      <code key="status1" code="123" title="STATUS1"/>
      <code key="status2" code="456" title="STATUS2"/>  
    </sections>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="data" select="$header/sections/code[@key=&quot;status1&quot;]" />
  <xsl:variable name="data1" select="$header/sections/code[@key=$key1]" />
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
        :<xsl:value-of select="$header" />:
        :<xsl:value-of select="$data" />:
        :<xsl:value-of select="$data/@title" />:
        :<xsl:value-of select="$data1/@title" />:
  </xsl:template>
     
</xsl:transform>
```

trying the transformation with command prompt as below :

```
java -cp saxon-he-10.5.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform Response.xml test.xsl > output.xml
```

Comment: it is not dependent on XML file so did not mentioned same. desired output xml i want it simple text of title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `xpath-default-namespace` makes your code fail. If you really need the global declaration you have then you need to override it locally, as in `<xsl:variable name="data" select="$header/sections/code[@key=&quot;status1&quot;]" xpath-default-namespace=""/>`.