# Unable to store the data in a xsl variable from a related path

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, jboss, saxon

Recently upgraded from Saxon HE 9.7-8 to 10.5-he.jar

In one of my XSL file, not able to store the data in a variable when I am running on Jboss server EAP 7.3 and JDK 11 . Where as the same is working when I have tested in command prompt or the debugger tool.

XSL file

We are using the below namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://hl7.org/fhir"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:f1="urn:hl7-org:v3"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3"
  xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xmlns:lookup="http://lookup.data"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fn lookup sdtc xsl cda f1 xsi" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

<!--loading the XML file by using the below code. here medicalSystems is a global variable-->
<xsl:variable name="medicalSystems" select="document('medicalsystems.xml')"/>

<!--then we are trying to store the data the variable ms-->
 <xsl:param name="this" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="code" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="doc" select="/"/>    
     <xsl:variable name="ms"
      select="$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming/MedicalSystem[url/@value = $this]"/>
```

```
XML file content:medicalsystems.xml
<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <entry>
    <coming>
      <MedicalSystem>
        <url value="http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/"/>
        <identifier>
          <system value="urn:ietf:rfc:3986"/>
          <value value="urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.283"/>
        </identifier>
        <name value="COSMIC : Catalogue Of Somatic Mutations In Cancer"/>
      </MedicalSystem>
    </coming>
  </entry>
```

We have confirmed that the XML is loading properly in the class where as the variable ms is empty when we execute on Jboss. The same piece of code working fine when we are executing with Saxon9.7 version .
Any input will be helpful.

Comment: We don't see what `$this` or `.` is so it is hard to tell. Which checks do you run to see that "the XML is loading properly"? Can you `trace($medicalSystems)` or `<xsl:message select="$medicalSystems" terminate="no"/>` or insert e.g. `<debug><xsl:copy-of select="$medicalSystems"/></debug>` in the output? If all the previous checks show the content you expect, can you output `namespace-uri($medicalSystems/*)`?

Comment: Is this an attempt to solve the problem already raised in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817415/unable-to-load-xml-document-with-document? Or are two different persons running into a very similar problem? Nevertheless, the last questions in the comment sections were not answered.

Comment: Please try using doc() rather than document() as this may give better diagnostics.

Comment: @MartinHonnen We have added this code " count(doc('urls.xml')) " which gives 1 in the output, by which we are making sure the XML is loading in XSL file

Comment: Does that comment about `urls.xml` refer to the previous question? Here the file seems to have a different name. And we can't debug this current question if you don't provide more information.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, both the questions are related. The XML file name and the file which we are loading in XSL are same 'medicationsystem.xml' .
The output of namespace-uri($medicalSystems/*)  came as "http://hl7.org/fhir" which is default namespace in XSL file also available in XML file

Comment: @MichaelKay we have used doc() instead of document() but did not t got any clue. $this holds a value like "http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/" .

Comment: It is not really possible to tell why the code would fail in a certain environment without access to that environment. Does `$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming/MedicalSystem` at least select all elements you expect, including the one with `url/@value = 'http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/']`?

Comment: Tried to output  "$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming/MedicalSystem"  this got empty value. while printed " $medicalSystems/Bundle" got values like "&#xA;  &#xA;.." . I guess something going wrong while applying namespace, or may be the default-namespace in XSL and XML file. Please provide your thoughts

Comment: Start editing your question and showing precise and complete, formatted details of the debug attempt, i.e. the values of the various expressions you have tested. I can't infer anything from some shortened data thrown into a comment.

Comment: I am printing the statement in this way : 
 <xsl:attribute name="testSystem">
              <xsl:value-of select="$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming/MedicalSystem"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
 
output of all these statement is coming as empty( testSystem="")
"$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming/MedicalSystem"
"$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming"
"$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry"

output of this "$medicalSystems/Bundle" statement gave values like this "&#xA;  &#xA;    &#xA;      &#xA;        &#xA;        &#xA;          &#xA;          &#xA;        &#xA;        &#xA;      &#x"

Comment: Please edit your question and add any code samples there in a formatted and therefore easily readable way. And that using `<xsl:value-of select="$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming/MedicalSystem"/>` doesn't output anything can't surprise anyone, after all, judging from the sample, all data is in attribute values of child or descendant elements, so that attempt to output the string value of the element which doesn't contain any text data children or descendants can't show anything. So use `xsl:message` or `<debug><xsl:copy-of select="$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming/MedicalSystem"/></debug>`

Comment: This is the only code sample which I am trying to solve.
I have used xsl:message added the below statements

<xsl:attribute name="testSystem">
              <xsl:message select="$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming/MedicalSystem""/>
</xsl:attribute>

it has printed empty value in the response(testSystem="").

Added <debug><xsl:copy-of select="$medicalSystems/Bundle/entry/coming/MedicalSystem"/></debug>
Which is giving me one liner response only i.e "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" in the Jboss, when I executed in a debugger tool it gave the entire data.

Comment: Start selecting e.g. `<debug><xsl:copy-of select="$medicalSystem"/></debug>`, then e.g. `<debug><xsl:copy-of select="$medicalSystem/Bundle"/></debug>`.

Comment: After adding <debug><xsl:copy-of select="$medicalSystem"/></debug> or <debug><xsl:copy-of select="$medicalSystem/Bundle"/></debug> is giving stylesheet compilation issue. but when I executed same in Altova debugger the entire value printed in output xml. Do you think  the solution which mentioned in the below link is related?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014337/how-do-i-enable-xslt-2-0-processor-in-jboss-eap-6-1-server-to-get-rid-of-errors  . Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: getting extra namespace in the top level of the output xml with Saxon10.5 jar e.g "   <component>
        <structuredBody xmlns="">
            <component xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">"  . where as with 9.7.0-8 we are not getting that    e.g " <component>
        <structuredBody>
            <component>
                <section>"

Comment: Can you please consider to edit your question and insert any information there in a formatted way? The question shows `<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">` as the root element of the file you load, which file do you show in your debug information that has a  `component` (root?) element? As for the namespace differences, I think were are getting closer to explain the failure to select elements, but currently I am not sure where the difference comes from. Are parts of the documents built outside of XSLT/Saxon, with the DOM API?

Comment: All the xml will be build in side the DOM only .In the question which shows  "<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">" this in the medicalsystems.xml which we are loading into the Portion.xsl and fetching data from that . The Component is the root element of the final output xml . In the XSL file we have exclude-result-prefixes to avoid the namespaces .

Comment: @MartinHonnen We debugged the application and came across one difference where we saw empty name space in medicalsystems.xml file which we have printed the stream before transformation and with latest jar. difference is an extra xmlns="" as a part of <Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <entry xmlns="">....</entry></Bundle>. seems like something to do with namespace. refereed to other questions which you have answered . But still not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347520/xslt-element-selection-based-on-another-variable  An input will be helpful